# Unable to show faces message on xhtml page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am unable to show faces messages using facesMessage

**Bean code :**

```
if(condition){
    FacesContext fc=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    fc.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,"Rounding Rule Saved","R Saved"));
}
```

**View code :**

```
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" globalOnly="true" id="msgId"/>
```

But I am not getting messages, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

My project flow is :

1. User click on edit button on view page
2. Redirect to edit page
3. After submitting return to view page
4. Render message(which I am not getting)

**View code (rouning_rule_master.xhtml) :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"      
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      > 
    <ui:composition template="/pages/webEx_Template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <title>Rounding Rule Master</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/rounding_rule_master.css" />

            </h:head>
            <h:body>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="page_wrapper">

                        <div class="page_heading border_bottom">Rounding Rule Master</div>

                        <div class="form_div">
                            <h:form  id="roundingMasterFormId" >
                                <p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" globalOnly="true" id="MESSAGEID"/>
                                <div class="form_detail">
                                    <div class="float_right">
                                        <h:commandButton id="creataeBtn" action="#{roundingBean.createRoundingRule}" value="Create   Rounding Rule" class="createRelation"  >
                                            <p:ajax onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/>
                                        </h:commandButton>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>


                                    <div style="margin:10px 0;">
                                        <table id="roundingMasterTableId" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="role_detail_section">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Rounding Rule Id</th>
                                                    <th>Rounding Rule Name</th>
                                                    <th>Rounding Mode</th>
                                                    <th>Rounding Constant</th>
                                                    <th class="action">Action</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            <c:forEach items="#{roundingBean.roundingRuleList}" var="var" >
                                                <tr>    
                                                <h:inputHidden value="#{var.roundingRuleId}" /> 
                                                <td><h:outputText value="#{var.roundingRuleId}" /></td>
                                                <td><h:outputText value="#{var.roundingRuleName}" /></td>
                                                <td><h:outputText value="#{var.roundingMode.roundingModeName}" /></td>
                                                <td><h:outputText value="#{var.roundingIncrement}" /></td>
                                                <td>
                                                <p:commandLink value="Edit" styleClass="edit_icon" action="#{roundingBean.editRoundingRule    (var,true)}" immediate="true" process="@this" onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();">
                                                </p:commandLink>
                                                <p:commandLink id="deleteId" styleClass="remove_icon" action="#{roundingBean.deleteRoundingRule(var.roundingRuleId)}" immediate="true" update="@form" process="@this" oncomplete="addCSS()" onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();">
                                                    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure want to delete rounding rule ?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />Delete
                                                </p:commandLink>
                                                </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>




                                </div>

                                <p:confirmDialog styleClass="confirm" global="true" showEffect="fade" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" width="400">  
                                    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"/>  
                                    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"/>       
                                </p:confirmDialog>
                                <p:dialog styleClass="confirm" modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Loading..."
                                          draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" width="100"
                                          height="50">
                                    <div align="center">
                                        <p:graphicImage value="../images/loading.gif" width="50"
                                                        height="50" />
                                    </div>
                                </p:dialog>
                            </h:form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </h:body>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your program entering that `if` statement? Try debugging your program. Your code is note wrong (i am doing the same in a program and it's working).

Comment: yes its going inside if statement...same way I used in other module , there its workin fine but not working in current page..on which factor it depends

Comment: I believe the cause of this behavior is somewhere else in your code. Could you provide us more information? My guess is that a second (unaware) ajax request is preventing the messages from being displayed.

Comment: I have posted my view page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is your case. But if you redirect after generating the Messages, they are lost in the redirect process. You need to make sure there is no redirect in the faces config - or any other mean - in your page flow.

Comment: wao its working...thanks...I was stuck in this issue since 2 days.

Comment: Now I am stuck in other problem: I removed <redirect/> from nevigation to get FacesMessage but now my url is not geting changed whn I nevigate form one page to another. and If I press f5 on any page it push me to previous page